# Go shift count too large

Tags: go

In Go's [constant specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants), it is mentioned that:

> Numeric constants represent exact values of arbitrary precision and do not overflow.

So I tried

`const VeryVeryBigNumber = 1 << 200`

and it works. However, the biggest shift count I could try is 511 and using 512 will throw:

`shift count too large: 512`.

What does 512 represents? I have no intention to use it, I just want to know why is it limited to 511 in my machine (I'm using ubuntu 64 bit and go 1.9.2)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

512 is kind of an arbitrary limit. The only thing the spec says is:

> Implementation restriction: Although numeric constants have arbitrary
>   precision in the language, a compiler may implement them using an
>   internal representation with limited precision. That said, every
>   implementation must:
>
> Represent integer constants with at least 256 bits.

Unfortunately, the [comments around the limits](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/mpfloat.go#L16) don't give a reason.

At some point, a limit has to be used. I would recommend sticking to the required 256.

Comment: Ah, right there in the spec... Thanks for the answer and the code link.